# Properties File listener in Java?

Tags: java, properties, listeners

I have properties file. I want to use listeners. if some Values change in this file then i want to update my integers. So, Which classes or implements do i need to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JNotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/) to listen to file system events.

Comment: I use netbeans 6.7. I think there must be easy way to use.

Comment: No problem, carry on with that.

Answer (score 0):

JNotify simply check the proprety file regularly. You could do the same with a timer. No code examples since the languague is not specified.